# How to add radio and dropdown fileds in my pricing table?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

```
<div class="">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="pricingTable">`
            <div class="pricingTable-header">
                <h3 class="heading">Business</h3>
                <span class="subtitle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
                <div class="price-value">20`
                    <span class="currency">$</span>
                    <span class="month">/mo</span>
                </div>
            </div>`
            <ul class="pricing-content">
                <li>60GB Disk Space</li>
                <li>60 Email Accounts</li>
                <li>60GB Monthly Bandwidth</li>
                <li>15 Subdomains</li>
                <li>20 Domains</li>
            </ul>`<a href="#" class="read">sign up<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="read">sign up<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
</div>
```

Please check the code above and tell me how to add radio button and dropdown button into this pricing table form.  you can also check  [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f8okLgx0/1/) here

Comment: What are specific requirements? Just add radio and select tags.

Comment: where you need radio button and dropdown list in the table?

Comment: It looks like you're using Bootstrap? So you could look at the documentation, Radio buttons(http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls) you will also find drop downs in the docs.

Comment: Guys thanks for reply.  I want to add radio and drop down at before sign up button.  its should take radio and drop down text to process with sign up button

Comment: Here is the demo site [link](https://www.domainjerry.com/email.html?type=ECO)

Comment: You need to use AJAX to do that

Comment: Guys, please help.  how to use it?